# How to capture user input in dc?

Tags: input, dc

I'd like to handle user input in `dc`.

For `?`, `info dc` indicates:

```
'?'                                                                                                                                                   
    Reads a line from the terminal and executes it.  This command                                                                                    
    allows a macro to request input from the user.
```

However, if I type this command sequence to square a number, followed by my input `9`:

```
?d*p                                                                                                                                                  
9
```

I get:

```
dc: stack empty                                                                                                                                       
dc: stack empty                                                                                                                                       
dc: stack empty
```

Am I misinterpreting what `?` does?

Comment: What you need to realize is that when you give the command sequence `?d*p` followed by your input, say 9, then that 9 is placed after the `p` so that when dc executes d the stack is essentially empty. You can confirm this by giving the command seq `?zp` where `z` is the number of stack elements. You should see a zero proving that your input came after the p. Thence those stack empty messages that you are seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are running this dc code on the command line, then
after the `?` provide the input the number to populate the `stack` on which `dc` undertakes it's operations.

?

3

d*p

Will result:

9

Comment: Then is the `?` even required? Would just `3␤d*p␤` do the same?

Comment: @YiminRong Now the 3 is hardcoded in the stack. `?` is very much needed if you need to do a input from the user. For example, using GNU dc, if we do: `dc -e '?d*p'` then run it, it will ask for input after which it will square it and return the results.